# Speech to Text rest API is slow. How can it be improved?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I am using google cloud speech API(Rest) for speech to text conversion. It is taking almost 2.8 secs to convert 2 words. Is there any way to improve this and bring it down to below 1 sec?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) best practices, you can use the **StreamingRecognize** and **single_utterance** properties to optimize the recognition for short utterances and minimizes the latency of your calls.

Additionally, you can check the [Frame size](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices#frame_size) to verify you are not using a very large frame as it can add latency.

> A 100-millisecond frame size is recommended as a good tradeoff between
>   latency and efficiency.